# Which is correct "women's clothing" or "womens clothing"?

Tags: word-choice, possessives

When I typed the search into Google most of the responses were websites selling clothing and the ratio of womens versus women's was about 1:1. Searching for mens versus men's and the version with apostrophes appears almost 90% of the time. For boys versus boy's or girls versus girl's it is a 3:2 ratio in favor of no apostrophes.

So there's a general trend for leaving the apostrophe out. But "womens" looks wrong.

I suppose the same question applies to public bathrooms as well. Is the women's room or the womens room?

Comment: The "Is mens a valid word?" question has an interesting twist I had not considered: menswear. No apostrophe there either. I agree it should be closed as a duplicate of that question. I can't mark either answer below as fully correct.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/614821/2085).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Women's room is "correct" as it follows the typical orthography rules. There is the possessive 's after the word "women." Women's room is correct because you want to use the possessive (men's, women's).

"Womens" is "incorrect" by any standard. It should never appear.

Comment: Because *women* is already plural, so the only reason to add an *s* is to create a possessive, which requires an apostrophe.

Comment: ' "Womens" is "incorrect" by any standard. It should never appear.' _ This is just not true - see the references at the previous (linked) thread.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Isn't part of the role of grammarians and gurus to guide others in effectiveness and clarity of language? The acceptance of "womens" abandons the meanings of plurality and possession. Both the *s* and the apostrophe are not just  sclerotic attachments to a technicality, but  communication of meaningful information.

Comment: @bib I think that having the choice of apostrophe or not actually adds effectiveness and clarity. _They live five minutes from the dogs home_ vs _They live five minutes from the dogs' home_. And how is _Woodhouses Working Mens Club_ lacking in clarity? The acceptance of _womens_ conforms to shifts in usage of attributive nouns.

Comment: How about menswear and womenswear?

Answer (score 2):

**Singlular**

- man
- woman
- boy
- girl

**Plural**

- men
- women
- boys
- girls

**Names of clothing departments/restrooms (plural, non-possessive)**

- Men
- Women
- Boys
- Girls

**Names of clothing departments/restrooms (plural, possessive)**

- Men's
- Women's
- Boys'
- Girls'