# U.S Men's National Team or U.S Men National Team

Tags: possessives, compound-adjectives

Can you explain which one is correct or if both are correct, under which scenario one is more suitable than the other? I have this doubt in general, when to use nouns as adjectives or possession like in this example. Can you give me some pointers?

Comment: closely related: [Is it correct to say “I write children books”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case) and [Which is correct “women's clothing” or “womens clothing”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127283/which-is-correct-womens-clothing-or-womens-clothing)

Comment: `The answers in the linked question don't solve my problem.` What answers in which linked question? You mean the question linked in the comment above mine? But if a user doesn't read the comments, your edit will not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

"Men's" is idiomatic.

> The players on the U.S. Olympic men's basketball team never doubted they would be standing on the gold-medal platform....

[from ESPN](http://www.espn.com/olympics/basketball/story/_/id/17360849/2016-rio-olympics-us-romps-serbia-men-basketball-gold)

Either "men's" or "men" would be possible in terms of basic English grammar, but in practice, Americans almost always say "US Men's (or Women's) ___ team." For example, US Women's Gymnastics Team, or US Men's Olympic Swim team.

More examples at the [USA Gymnastics website](https://usagym.org/pages/athletes/womenList.html) or the [USA Basketball website](https://www.usab.com/mens/national-team/roster.aspx).

Comment: Could you provide examples when "men" is used to modify a group, or denote possession e.g. *The US men soccer team* (if it is called that)  or *men clothing*. I Would consider the second to be "ungrammatical", while the former sounds reasonable to my ears. Maybe you can come up with some better exceptions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "Why are tall women clothes so hard to find? ... I realize I have an entire website dedicated to clothing for taller ladies, but sometimes it’s just really frustrating even for me that tall women clothes are hard to find. It’d just be nice if they were more widely distributed within physical stores." (https://thetallgirlsguidetofashion.com/why-are-tall-women-clothes-so-hard-to-find). Women Veterans Alliance; New Mothers Support Group; The Women Executives Forum; Cancer Survivors Network